# Xamarin How can i change label text color if it contains minus

Tags: c#, xamarin

So i need to change label color if it have positive or negative balance.

```
<Label x:Name="label" Text="$ -100"/>
```

I've tried by checking does it contains minus.

```
if( label.Text.Contains("-"))
 labe.TextColor = Color.Red;
else
label.TextColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: How are you calling this code. And why do you care with a label? Just set the color in xaml

Comment: the code you have should work, or you could use an IValueConverter if you are using data binding

Comment: I have task to do that shows changes the color of that label when u start app, so if we set it to $ -100 to show red, and if it is positive to show green. I'm calling this method in public MainPage right after initializeComponent. But it's not working for color RED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#the-ivalueconverter-interface) to achieve this:

Here i test wtih a button,when i click the button i will change the label text and change its color.

create  **ColorConvert**  class:

```
class ColorConvert : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string s = (string)value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            if (s.Contains("-"))
            {
                return Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                return Color.Green;
            }
        }
        return Color.Green;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

then in your xaml ：

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ColorConvert x:Key="colorConvert" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label x:Name="label1" Text="$ 100" TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference label1},Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource colorConvert}}">
    </Label>

    <Button Text="click" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

in the .xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "$ -100";
    }
```

the effect :

[image]